# Make AJAX "get" function synchronous / how to get the result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I'm experiencing a problem of $.get function.
The url contains JSON

***my code:***

```
 xyz = null

    $.get('http://www.someurl.com/123=json', function(data) {
       var xyz = data.positions[0].latitude;
    });

alert(xyz);
//some more code using xyz variable
```

I know that `xyz` will alert a null result because the `$.get` is **asynchronous**.

So is there any way I can use the `xyz` outside this get function?

Comment: If you move the `var` keyword out of your function and in front of your initial `xyz` then you can use it anywhere in that scope in any function that executes after your ajax request completes.

Comment: While there *is* **synchronous** AJAX (it's *documented* in jQuery), it should usually *be avoided* because of the negative impact it has on the user experience. Instead, focus on using the event-based model of asynchronous AJAX. That is, update the DOM with `xyz` *from within* the callback.

Comment: @pst. Same question all the time. This one and the DOM ready problem.

Comment: @gdoron Nope, not the "DOM ready", the "return variable from AJAX get" ;-) Lemme get some dupes...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973681/jquery-how-to-use-the-return-value-of-an-ajax-call-outside-that-ajax-call?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375046/jquery-ajax-call-return-value-problem?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483921/cant-set-an-variable-in-jquery-getjson-function?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633051/jquery-ajax-get-result , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546339/jquery-assign-json-as-a-result-to-a-variable

Comment: @pst. Nice list you got over there... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The real answer is **NO**, but you can use this:

```
function useXYZ(){
    alert(xyz);
}

xyz = null        

$.get('http://www.someurl.com/123=json', function(data) {
   xyz = data.positions[0].latitude;
   useXYZ();
});
```

Comment: Why waste time and mental confusion on a global property? (Or closured variable). It is often better written as `function useXYZ(xyz) {..}`... and then pass through the data from the callback.

Comment: @pst. I thought to do so, but I wanted to show him how he can use the outer variable. (BTW, it doesn't have to be a global variable). You can edit as you wish sir!

Comment: Thanks! Thought it work well with alert I'm still having trouble with the rest of the script. And actually when I have to put a lot of stuff inside the function useXYZ(){ ... }

Answer (score 23):

`get` is a shortcut. You can do the same, but synchronous, using:

```
var xyz = null


$.ajax({ url: 'http://www.someurl.com/123=json', 
         async: false,
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {
              xyz = data.positions[0].latitude;
            }
        });


alert(xyz);
```

You'll have to declare the `xyz` variable before the ajax call, though.

Comment: Well, in all honesty my initial answer was poor. I should really stop trying to answer questions from my phone.

Comment: In Chrome and firefox i'm still getting a null. In safari works well

Comment: Hmm. I've tested with Safari, Chrome, and Firefox (on OSX). Here's a pure example http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/F2Ey5/1/

Comment: OSX here as well. In concept it seems correct (with async: false ) but I don't know... Maybe there's smthng with json. I'm not much of an expert. Thanks though!

Answer (score 4):

This is a common issue with Javascript. Javascript code must be written in continuation passing style. Its annoying but its something you can convert without thinking too much.

Basicaly, whenever we would have something like

```
var x = someSyncFunction(a, b, c);
//do something with x
console.log(x);
```

We can convert it into async code by making all the code after the function returns into a continuation function and turning x from a variable into a parameter of the continuation callback.

```
someAsyncFunction(a, b, c, function(x){
    //do something with x;
    console.log(x);
});
```

You have to watch out that its very easy to write confusing code. A good trick to keep in mind is taht you can make your own functions also receive callbacks. This allows them to be used by different function (just like normal sync helper functions that return a value can be used by different functions)

```
var getXyz = function(onResult){ //async functions that return do so via callbacks
                                 //you can also another callback for errors (kind of analogous to throw)
    $.get('http://www.someurl.com/123=json', function(data) {
       var xyz = data.positions[0].latitude;
        onResult(xyz); //instead of writing "return xyz", we pass x to the callback explicitely.
    });
};

getXyz(function(xyz){ //this would look like "var xyz = getXyz();" if it were sync code instead.
    console.log('got xyz');
});
```

The trick here is to change all return statements from the function into calls to the callback function. Think as if async function never returned and the only way to give a value back to someone is to pass that value to a callback.

---

You might ask why there isnt an easier way to do all of this. Well, there is not, unless you use another language instead of Javascript (or at least something that lets you write async code in synchronous style but automatically compiles down to regular Javascript)

Comment: Thanks! What if I had to grab two vars from the JSON like "xyz" for the latitude and "abc" for the longtitude? How would the onResult be and function(xyz). Could I nest them both inside it or should I create a second function(abc) ?

Comment: You could package both values inside a single object and pass the object to the callback `onResult({lat:xyz, long:abc});`, similarly to how you would return multiple values from a synchronous function) or you could have the callback function receive two parameters instead of one `onResult(xyz, abc);`. Having more then one callback is usualy for different and mutually exclusive computation paths. A common example is having one success (or "return") callback and one error (or "throw") callback.